# google form result to a table

Tags: excel, forms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKO2T.png)

I want to automatically change the google form result to a table.

The user will submit the name and workday by google form. I want the workday can auto display on that day.

It means if the workday is Mon and Tue, I want the table can show the name on Mon and Tue.

Comment: The question is not clear, can you please elaborate it ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the 1st column is column A, put this in E13 :

```
=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH(E$12,$C13),D13,""),"")
```

Is this what you r looking for?

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGuZ6.png)

=IF(COUNTIF($J2,"*mon*"),$I2,)

I2 = user name
J2 = workday